# Entity framework Lazy loading perfomance

Tags: entity-framework

I need to take user's last 100 messages
I have generated 1 million messages to the database
Can someone explain to me why this is taking ~7000ms

```
var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == userid);
var messages = user.Messages.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(100);
```

While this one is fast as ~1ms

```
var messages = db.Messages.Where(x => x.UserID == userid).OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(100);
```

Comment: Because, at this case, you load all Messages from DB and then on client side execute Take(100).

Answer (score 0):

Using Take() does not impact the db engine's workload - what happens is the db engine selects ALL the records matching the query and then returns the top 100 (I think SQL Server 2014 may have improved on this with the engine only selecting the required records).

Thus the first query is actually forcing the db engine to select all the records before filtering for the first 100.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to load only last 100 but with something similar to my first code?

Comment: Why are you not using the second block? - it looks as if this provides exactly what you are requesting.

Answer (score 0):

Best Approach I would use in this scenario is to use Stored Procedure.

As it seems that there is large amount of data in the table so at some point **LINQ** would loose its performance. It will be a good approach to shift selecting logic to the DBMS.

SQL SERVER keeps **Stored Procedure's** result in its own cache as compiled set of queries. So the execution will be fast definitely.

Just try to create new Stored Procedure having following query

```
SELECT TOP 100 [Your Column Names] FROM [TABLENAME] ORDER BY UserID  DESC
```

Add stored procedure into entity model then import function and check your data fetching performance will be improved.

Hope That Helps. :)

Comment: Thank you a lot, but the thing is that I can write whole site logic using pure T-SQL of course, but I love Entity Framework, because I write object orientated code and don't mind about sql itself.. But thanks ;)

Comment: It's a good thing if you want to write object oriented code. Then I would suggest you to do some tweak to improve performance of entity framework. This link might be helpfull https://developingsoftware.com/increase-enity-framework-performance